# C++ UTF8 Encoding

Tags: c++, encoding

I have UTF8 codes: 72 101 108 108 111 33 .
It means "Hello!". How can I encode it using C++?
I know that there is a function called wcstombs but I don't understand how it works.

Comment: `std::string s="Hello!";` Mission accomplished. `wcstombs()` is for converting wide characters to a multi-byte character string. A UTF-8 string is a multi-byte character string, so `wcstombs()` is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Your question is unclear, do you wish to write a program that converts the UTF-8 string to Hello, or vice versa?

Comment: The input is: 72 101 108 108 111 33
The output must be: Hello!

Comment: Yes, but what do you want to do with that input?

Comment: I want to turn it string

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your problem is. Seems like it's not an utf-8 or encoding problem.

If your input is text "72 101 108 108 111 33", convert text to int and then to char.

```
int main()
{
    stringstream ss("72 101 108 108 111 33");
    int n;
    string s;
    while (ss >> n) {
        s.push_back(static_cast<char>(n));
    }
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

If your input is int array, just cast int to char.